# while importing SMOTEENN from imblearn.combine, ImportError is :"cannot import name get_max_squared_sum"

Tags: python, scikit-learn

during importing SMOTEENN from imblearn.combine, I get the error : cannot import name get_max_squared_sum".

The log of error is :

---

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/sag.py", line 14, in 
    from .sag_fast import sag, get_max_squared_sum
ImportError: cannot import name get_max_squared_sum

---

What needs to be done? I could not locate its solution on internet.

Regards
cosmos

Comment: Looks like other requirements like `scipy` and `numpy` are not installed. Please install them and also I think you are using an older version of scikit-learn. Maybe 0.17. Please try upgrading to latest.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you didnt installed imblearn. try this it should work:

```
pip install -U imbalanced-learn
```

Comment: I installed imbalance learn by 'python setup.py install". pip is not allowed at my place. Any other suggestion?